# Use one 2dim array instead of two 1dim arrays in working maco

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am searching a column for blanks cells, if I find one then I want to copy the two preceding cells adjacent to the blank cell and post to new sheet.

blksArray is the Column I am Searching for blanks.

emailArray and nameArray are the adjacent columns to copy cells from if blank is found in blksArray

The macro works but I was hoping I could use a single Array in place of the two arrays emailArray and nameArray

Thank you

Edit: Sorry if I was confusing
Source Sheet:

```
Name    Emails            XXX
Bill    Bill@Bill.com     abc    
Tony    Tony@Tony.com
Roger   Roger@Roger.com   aaa
Diane   Diane@Diane.com   bbb
Pam     Pam@Pam.com
Barb    Barb@Barb.com
Ziggy   Ziggy@Ziggy.com   ddd
```

Target Sheet:

```
Name    Emails            XXX 
Tony    Tony@Tony.com
Pam     Pam@Pam.com
Barb    Barb@Barb.com
```

Code:

```
Sub MoveCellsIfEmpty()
Dim blankArray As Variant, textArray As Variant
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim wsT As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NodeFile")
Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blanks")

With wsS
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '\\ search column
    blksArray = .Range("E2:E" & LR).Value

   '\\ Cells to copy
   emailArray = .Range("D2:D" & LR).Value
    nameArray = .Range("C2:C" & LR).Value

        For i = LBound(blksArray, 1) To UBound(blksArray, 1)
            If IsEmpty(blksArray(i, 1)) Then
               emailArray(i, 1) = emailArray(i, 1)
                nameArray(i, 1) = nameArray(i, 1)
            Else
                emailArray(i, 1) = ""
                 nameArray(i, 1) = ""
            End If
        Next i
End With

'\\ Post back to target sheet
With wsT
     .Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = nameArray
     .Range("B2:B" & LR).Value = emailArray
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I redid my answer using a single array.  I when you read a range into an array apparently, it creates a 2 dimensional array of spreadsheet coordinates (who knew!?) so rather than creating multiple arrays and trimming them down or re-adding them to a new array, i just created the ray and then cycled through adding them to the new sheet if that third value is blank.  I ran it on 104,000 records and it took maybe 3 or 4 seconds.  Hopefully this is more on the money for what you are after :)

```
Sub MoveCellsIfEmpty()
Dim blankArray() As Variant
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim wsT As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NodeFile")
Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blanks")

With wsS
    LR = (.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    blankArray = .Range("A2:C" & LR)
End With

j = 1
For i = 1 To LR - 1
     If blankArray(i, 3) = "" Then 'if blank paste to new sheet
        wsT.Range("A" & j).Value = blankArray(i, 1)
        wsT.Range("B" & j).Value = blankArray(i, 2)
        j = j + 1
     End If


Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tbizzess thank you for you responce, I `edited` my question to make it more clear (sorry about that).  I am using arrays because the data sets are large and also I am re-purposing a macro I already had that seems to work well.

Comment: Wow thanks for the code and the text both were equally helpful